# How can I send a message to all players in the minecraft server?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-java-edition-server

Currently I am hosting a minecraft server, and I as the operator would like to send a "server message", so all the players can read it, instead of me sending the message specifically to each and every player. How can this be done? I looked online, but they all suggest the /msg keyword, which does not work anymore.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You'd want to use [`say`](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands/say):

```
  say <message …>
```

> Fails if any target selectors do not resolve to at least one online player, or if any named players are not online.

> On success, broadcasts message to all players on the server. If a multi-person target selector (e.g., @a) is used in message, the list of names is formatted as "name1 and name2" for two players, or "name1, name2, ... and nameN" for N players. Target selectors are not recognized in Pocket Edition.

For example:
`say Hello world`

https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands/say

Comment: Might I inquire why the answer was downvoted recently if the user returns? I edited it to update dead links but I can't tell if I missed something or if it's incorrect. Please let me know if so.

Comment: Codingale, nothing about the answer is incorrect or needs improvement. I've seen and experienced many times good answers randomly get downvoted and its so confusing and I've come to the conclusion that either (a.) StackExchange might have an algorithm for randomly downvoting answers, or (b.) there are just some nasty people who always downvote everything they see.

Answer (score 4):

Just press t and type the message and press enter